Как правильно организовать структуру MySQL для нескольких участников работающих над одним заказом?
Есть база данных с заказами. Есть общая стоимость заказа и начисление каждому кто участвует в формировании этого заказа. А именно [площадка, формирующий заказ чел, и его менеджер]. Для каждого такого нужно прописать сумму и логин.
Как организовано сейчас, показано на скрине.
Возможно в будущем будут еще уровни, и таблица не будет удобочитаемой.
Если есть опыт, посоветуйте, как сделать лучше?
Правильно ли вообще все хранить в одной "широкой" таблице, или для этого используют какие то еще способы?

id - номер заказа
all_sum - общая стоимость заказа
me_sun - начисление площадки
adder_login - формирующий заказ человек
adder_sum - выплата формирующему заказ
parent_login - менеджер человека формирующего заказ
parent_sum - выплата менеджеру...
... остальные поля для моего вопроса значения не имеют...


Если планируются еще какие-то участники механизма выплат, то, на мой взгляд, целесообразнее вынести ИД получателей и их выплаты в отдельную сущность БД. Как альтернативу можно рассмотреть хранение ИД участников и их выплат в виде Json-поля
